# ASP .NET Core cookie authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API site that is using an authentication cookie generated from another ASP.NET Web Form site.
Since both the ASP.NET Web API site and the ASP.NET Web Form site have the same "machineKey" and same "form auth cookie name", it would allow a user to login to the "Web Form Site" and then pull data from the "Web API Site" without re-authentication since the "auth" cookie would pass between sites.
All this was done inside that web.config and did not require any special code to work.

Now we would like to create an ASP NET Core Web API site and have that same auth cookie work.

I can't seem to find any good articles on how do this in .NET Core.
There are plenty of articles on how to us ASP Identity which we don't have and plenty of articles on auth cookies but none explaining how to get it from another site...

Here is the web.config sections that I had in the Web API:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication>
      <forms name=".TESTAUTH" cookieless="AutoDetect" requireSSL="true" domain=".test.com" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" timeout="600"
             enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
    </authentication>

    <!-- This is used to share the auth cookie between web sites -->
    <machineKey validationKey="SOMEKEY"
                decryptionKey="SOMEOTHERKEY" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" compatibilityMode="Framework20SP2" />
  </system.web>
```

**EDIT A**
We are using "Framework20SP2" and that seems to complicate the issue.
Here is a link to some code that will decrypt the auth ticket based on "Framework20SP2"
https://github.com/dazinator/AspNetCore.LegacyAuthCookieCompat

If I use the NuGet above, it does decrypt the auth cookie in the .NET Core site but I can't seem to figure out how to get that to work in the .NET Core DataProtectionProvider.

Comment: I'm the owner of that project, did you manage to figure this out in the end? What do you mean by "figure out how to get that to work in the .NET Core DataProtectionProvider." ? To my knowledge you can't use DPAPI in .net core to decrypt cookie payloads from legacy .net such as Framework20SP2.

Comment: @Darrell I did get this to work. I have an ASP.NET 3.5 Website that generates the login cookie and an ASP.NET Core 3.1 site the consumes the cookie and it seems to decrypt the cookie just fine.

Comment: Yup, using my spectacular package right? DPAPI (DataProtectionProvider) doesn't enter into that equation, it's something else, so that's what confused me ;-)... aaaaanyway! glad you got it all working!

Comment: @Darrell You are correct in that I did not get it to work with the DataProtectionProvider and instead used your spectacular product...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to confirm is that the applications are hosted on same domain or subdomains of that domain . Otherwise consider using token/sso service like Identity Server 4/Azure AD to implement SSO .

ASP.NET 4.x apps that use Katana Cookie Authentication Middleware can be configured to generate authentication cookies that are compatible with the ASP.NET Core Cookie Authentication Middleware .Install the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop` package into ASP.NET 4.x app to use DataProtectionProvider , which provides data protection services for the encryption and decryption of authentication cookie payload data.

You can now remove machineKey config , the Katana cookies middleware uses  data protection , that doesn't rely on machine keys but on a key ring persisted ,you should ensure that it uses a persisted key storage, and that key storage is accessible and used by each application .

See below article for more details and code sample :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have looked at that link before but it suggested that I edit the current ASP.NET site which in my case is .NET 3.5 and has been around for 10+ years and as such is not an option to edit. I'm still trying to piece some of the information together. I will add more info into the question above.

Comment: `An ASP.NET 4.x app must target .NET Framework 4.5.1 or later. Otherwise, the necessary NuGet packages fail to install.` If the project can't be edit, you can't share cookie between it and .net core app, as .net core app use the new data protection and don't rely on machine key,

Answer (score 0):

While this works, I'm not 100% sure it is the best / proper way of doing this but
here is the main class I created.

```cs
public class FormsAuthCookieTicketFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
{

    private LegacyFormsAuthenticationTicketEncryptor _Encryptor;
    private Sha1HashProvider _HashProvider;

    public FormsAuthCookieTicketFormat(string decryptionKey, string validationKey)
    {
        byte[] decryptionKeyBytes = HexUtils.HexToBinary(decryptionKey);
        byte[] validationKeyBytes = HexUtils.HexToBinary(validationKey);

        _Encryptor = new LegacyFormsAuthenticationTicketEncryptor(decryptionKeyBytes, validationKeyBytes, ShaVersion.Sha1, CompatibilityMode.Framework20SP2);
        _HashProvider = new Sha1HashProvider(validationKeyBytes);
    }

    public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data, string purpose)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText, string purpose)
    {
        var ticket = _Encryptor.DecryptCookie(protectedText);


        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("MyCookie");
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, ticket.Name));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.IsPersistent, ticket.IsPersistent.ToString()));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Expired, ticket.Expired.ToString()));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Expiration, ticket.Expiration.ToString()));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.CookiePath, ticket.CookiePath));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Version, ticket.Version.ToString()));

        // Add some additional properties to the authentication ticket.
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties();
        props.ExpiresUtc = ticket.Expiration.ToUniversalTime();
        props.IsPersistent = ticket.IsPersistent;

        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);


        var authTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, props, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        return authTicket;
    }
}
```

Here is the Startup.cs file

```
var formsCookieFormat = new FormsAuthCookieTicketFormat(decryptionKey, validationKey);

services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = ".TESTCOOKIE";
        options.Cookie.Domain = ".TESTDOMAIN";
        options.Cookie.Path = "/";
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login/";
        options.LoginPath = "/Login/";
        options.ReturnUrlParameter = "returnurl";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.TicketDataFormat = formsCookieFormat;
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });
```